# Chef Server Installation error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I am a newbie to chef. I am trying to install chef server on an ec2 centos instance.

I am following [this link](http://sanketdangi.com/post/50649257357/chef-11-configuration-aws-ec2-rhel-6-3-instance) to install the chef server.

But I am getting error at step 8 of installation.

```
[root@ip-10-105-203-174 ~]# knife configure -i
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ohai-7.0.4/lib/ohai/loader.rb:188: warning: character class has `[' without escape
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ohai-7.0.4/lib/ohai/loader.rb:188: warning: regexp has `]' without escape
Overwrite /root/.chef/knife.rb? (Y/N)Y
Please enter the chef server URL: [https://ip-10-105-23-174:443] https://10.105.23.174
Please enter a name for the new user: [root]
Please enter the existing admin name: [admin]
Please enter the location of the existing admin's private key: [/etc/chef-server/admin.pem]
Please enter the validation clientname: [chef-validator]
Please enter the location of the validation key: [/etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem] /root/.chef/chef-server/chef-validator.pem
Please enter the path to a chef repository (or leave blank):
Creating initial API user...
Please enter a password for the new user:
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.203.174/users, retry 1/5
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.203.174/users, retry 2/5
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.203.174/users, retry 3/5
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.203.174/users, retry 4/5
ERROR: Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.203.174/users, retry 5/5
ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - Connection refused connecting to https://10.105.23.174/users, giving up
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Is this the right tutorial. Please help me resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you add the output of: `sudo chef-server-ctl status`

Comment: The issue is resolved. the hostname was not resolvable.

Comment: Could you please share your knife configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing the right thing for chef, but it looks like a fundamental networking issue. If I understand properly, you are logged into the chef server and trying to set up knife on the same box to talk contact itself. Is Chef server actually running? Use 'netstat -an' and verify that something is waiting on the :443 port. Can you use a browser from another host to contact it? You could also consider installing "knife" on another machine and running the same thing.

Comment: All the ports in the security group are opened !! And I am giving the correct url 10.105.203.174. Do i need to install apache for chef ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing a valid chef-server url. At first look it looks like you are giving the workstation ip address.

Comment: I am giving the same IP where the chef server is installed 10.105.203.174. also all the ports are enabled in the security group. Kindly help

Comment: how to make the hostname rsolvable? I think this is the issue

Comment: Add an entry to the /etc/hosts file for the server.

Something like this

10.105.203.174 Hostname of the sever

Comment: Also i would recomend to set the hostname of your server first rather than leaving it to amazon managed hostname. 

Then again run chef-server-ctl reconfigure on your server.


After this is completed.Try configuring your workstation.